# How to install any latest version of any c/c++ library over an old one

Tags: c++, libraries, opencv

I want to install the latest version of OpenCV on my linux distro [ Kali ] i.e OpenCV 4.0.1 over OpenCV 3.4.3 . Will there be any problems if I directly install OpenCV 4.0.1 ? Just to make this question a general one i.e the answer can be used with any library not only OpenCV, my final question is  : How to install latest version of a c/c++ library over an old one ?

I have experienced problems with these situations in my previous installations.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

if you use a supported version of Ubuntu the software can be updated by `sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/355565/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-cmake-from-the-command-line/355574

Comment: I know that but I am asking for libraries not packages. Please go through the question once more.